# Laravel 5.8: Error Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**I saw similar questions but non of them work for me**. This is the `Transition` model

```
class Transition extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['origin_x', 'origin_y', 'destination_x', 'destination_y', 'freight_id', 'status', 'receiver_name', 'receiver_mobile', 'receiver_address'];
 protected $table = 'freight_transitions';
}
```

and this is the insertion code

```
    $transition = Transition::create([
        'origin_x' => $redis['origin_x'],
        'origin_y' => $redis['origin_y'],
        'destination_x' => $redis['destination_x'],
        'destination_y' => $redis['destination_y'],
        'freight_id' => $freight->id,
        'status' => 2,
        'receiver_name' => $redis['receiver_name'],
        'receiver_mobile' => $redis['receiver_mobile'],
        'receiver_address' => $redis['receiver_address']
    ]);
```

I am sure the array of $redis` has value. But this is the error

> General error: 1364 Field 'origin_x' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `freight_transitions` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-11-02 16:42:58, 2019-11-02 16:42:58))

From what I see, the Laravel does not try to insert the `origin_x` and other fields in to the DB. it only inserts the `created_at` and `updated_at`. I have a similar model called `Freight`, in a few lines above this code, I insert records in the same way with no error. But I don't know why it only inserts the  `created_at` and `updated_at`.

I also tried

```
$transition = new Transition([....]);//array of above data
$transition->save();
```

It also generates the same error.

This is the migration

```
    Schema::create('freight_transitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('origin_x');
        $table->string('origin_y');
        $table->string('destination_x');
        $table->string('destination_y');
        $table->string('receiver_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('receiver_mobile')->nullable();
        $table->string('receiver_address')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('freight_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('freight_id')->references('id')->on('freight_freights')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->enum('status', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'])->default(1);//1: start
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this is `redis` array in json format

```
{
"origin_x": "555",
"origin_y": "666",
"destination_x": "777",
"destination_y": "8888",
"freight_type_id": "1",
"title": null,
"description": null,
"price": 130000,
"features": "2",
"services": "2,5",
"vehicle_id": 1,
"token": "111111",
"payment_type": "3",
"user_id": 1,
"receiver_name": null,
"receiver_mobile": null,
"receiver_address": null,
"payment_status": 1,
"status": 2
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show where the `$redis` array comes from?

Comment: @Saly3301 I am sure it has value from `dd`. It comes from Redis server package. As you see the error is because it doesnt try to insert any value for `origin_x` and other fields

Comment: I can't reproduce only with the code you have provided, please add the output of `dd($redis);`

Comment: is that the output of `return $redis;` or `dd($redis);`? is `$redis` an object or an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to insert data as follows

```
    $transition = new Transition;
    $transition ->origin_x = $redis['origin_x'];
    $transition ->origin_y = $redis['origin_y'];
    $transition ->destination_x = $redis['destination_x'];
    $transition ->destination_y = $redis['destination_y'];
    $transition ->freight_id = $freight->id;
    $transition ->status = 2;
    $transition ->receiver_name = $redis['receiver_name'];
    $transition ->receiver_mobile = $redis['receiver_mobile'];
    $transition ->receiver_address = $redis['receiver_address'];
    $transition->save();
```

Even though it works, but it is still a question to me why the codes I use for tons of projects doesn't work here :|

Comment: I find it better to mark none of the fields guarded instead of all of them fillable, i.e `protected $guarded = [];`

Comment: @Saly3301 Laravel documentation strongly recommended to save the fields in `fillable`

Comment: Laravel documentation recommends not using Mass Assignment at all

Comment: @Saly3301 you are right. but here is a point. Fillable lets you specify which fields is mass-assignable in your model. Hence by specifying them in Fillable there must be no error

Answer (score -2):

Did you convert your json into array if not convert it into array using json_decode function of php and try again. if possible then give default value to your columns.

Comment: Please include this as a comment to the question. If you can give a more detailed answer with accompanying code then put it here.

Comment: The code `$transition = Transition::create([ ... ])` clearly shows the data is in array.

Comment: i am asking you , did not convert json into array?

Comment: The json is only to show the data. The data is actually an array

Comment: create is use to save data into database that take value in array format. and we must pass value as array to create function

Comment: {
"origin_x": "555",
"origin_y": "666",
"destination_x": "777",
"destination_y": "8888",
"freight_type_id": "1",
"title": null,
"description": null,
"price": 130000,
"features": "2",
"services": "2,5",
"vehicle_id": 1,
"token": "111111",
"payment_type": "3",
"user_id": 1,
"receiver_name": null,
"receiver_mobile": null,
"receiver_address": null,
"payment_status": 1,
"status": 2
}   this json not an array

Comment: This is data in array `$transition = Transition::create([
        'origin_x' => $redis['origin_x'],
        'origin_y' => $redis['origin_y'],
        'destination_x' => $redis['destination_x'],
        'destination_y' => $redis['destination_y'],
        'freight_id' => $freight->id,
        'status' => 2,
        'receiver_name' => $redis['receiver_name'],
        'receiver_mobile' => $redis['receiver_mobile'],
        'receiver_address' => $redis['receiver_address']
    ]);`

Comment: in php json is as string but javascript json work as array but its not same for php

Comment: @NiteshMangla the OP's code example of using `create` is passing an array ... `[ ... ]`